# Spring Security, не получается добавить картинку на сервер, ошибка доступа 403

Tags: java, spring-security

конфигурация

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers().permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/add").access("hasAuthority('USER')")
            .antMatchers("/user").access("hasAuthority('USER')")
            .antMatchers("/admin").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .permitAll();
}
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.
            userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

}

permitAll() тоже не получается

Контроллер

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file, Model model){

    Foto foto = new Foto();
    if(file!=null && !file.getOriginalFilename().isEmpty()){
        File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);
        if (!uploadDir.exists()){
            uploadDir.mkdir();
        }

        String uuidFile = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String resultFilename = uuidFile + "." + file.getOriginalFilename();

        try {
            file.transferTo(new File(uploadPath + "/" + resultFilename));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        foto.setFileName(resultFilename);
    }

    return "index";
}
```

без SPring Security  работает нормально файлы загружаются по адресу. С SpringSecutiry в браузере после загрузки файла пишет 403 ошибку

> There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
>   Forbidden

Comment: Попробуйте к auth добавить `.csrf().disable()`

Comment: Это не совсем то, что нужно бы использовать, просто хочу убедиться, что проблема в этом

Comment: спасибо, заработало. я поменял мусташ на фримаркер.

Comment: хотя сиэсэрэф токен к мушташ добавлял, не понимаю в чем была проблема

Comment: Дак мой ответ помог или нет?)

Comment: помог, а можно как нибудь не отключая csrf

Comment: Разобрался, скобку забыл написать, оттого csrf не работал, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{_csrf.token}}" />
```

проблема заключалась в csrf токене